# What does the "\" mean in java properties files?

Tags: java, properties, escaping

Hi I am processing some java .proeprties files.

I'm wondering what does the "\" mean in the end of the a line, for example:

```
pay.checkPrint.shellfish=You need to be the target of feature. \
    Features are setup.  <a id="desclink" href="{0  }">Click here</a> to work.
```

Is it the same as the following?

```
pay.checkPrint.shellfish=You need to be the target of feature. Features are setup.  <a id="desclink" href="{0  }">Click here</a> to work.
```

Penny

Comment: afaik, yes, it is. see https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23095_01/Platform.93/ATGProgGuide/html/s0204propertiesfileformat01.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a simple way to escape end line character.

From the [Oracle ATG Programming Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23095_01/Platform.93/ATGProgGuide/html/s0204propertiesfileformat01.html) (i've see this link has also been linked in a comment):

> A property value can span several lines if each line is terminated by
>   a backslash (‘\’) character. For example:
>
> ```
> targetCities=\  
>       Detroit,\  
>       Chicago,\  
>       Los Angeles
> ```
>
> This is equivalent to `targetCities=Detroit,Chicago,Los Angeles` (white
>   space at the beginning of lines is ignored).

EDIT:
As suggested by @erickson i'm adding to the answer the authoritative specification for [`Properties`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load-java.io.Reader-)

Comment: A much better reference would be the authoritative specification: [`Properties`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load-java.io.Reader-)

Comment: @erickson I've added the reference in the answer to complete it, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The (truly) definitive specification for the simple `Properties` file syntax is the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load-java.io.InputStream-) for `Properties.load(Reader)` which says:

> *"A logical line holds all the data of a key-element pair, which may be spread out across several adjacent natural lines by escaping the line terminator sequence with a backslash character `\`."*

(The Oracle ATG text that people have been quoting is a secondary source.)

---

So the answer to your question is Yes.  Those are two ways of expressing the same thing.  It is your choice which you use, but (personally) I *would* use `\` to deal with overly long lines to aid readability.